# Ping no me responde pero puedo acceder a la página ¿por qué?

Tags: cmd

Tengo una página alojada en un servidor local, a esta le creamos el dns sistemasissa.ml para acceder externamente sin tener que escribir la dirección IP publica, el tema es, al hacer ping localmente me responde correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al hacer lo mismo desde un equipo externo, no responde:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo extraño es que ellos sí pueden acceder a la página, la pagina es http://sistemasissa.ml:8019/

¿Por qué sucede esto? y ¿cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: Seguramente tengas la regla en el firewall bloqueada, por eso no te responde

Comment: Tengo el firewall completamente desactivado

Comment: Una cosa es cómo se configura en la red de tu empresa para enrutar las peticiones a un servidor web, y otra es cómo una petición ICMP llega. Funcionan por puertos diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

Si el host que queres hacer ping es un windows 10, por mas que tengas el firewall desactivado no te va a responder.

tenes que ir a la configuracion avanzada del firewall y habilitar la opcion de reglas entrantes, la que dice `Archivos e impresoras compartidos (petición eco: ICMPv4 de entrada)`

Para llegar ahi tenes que entrar al firewall (busca Windows Firewall) y ahi el link que dice Configuraciones Avanzadas.

Un saludo y espero que te sirva.

Comment: El DNS lo tomé de freenom, no sé si tenga algo que ver

Comment: A ver si entendi, tenes una pc en tu lan con un nombre y queres hacerle ping desde afuera (osea internet), si es eso no se por que conteste lo de Windows 10, pero desestimalo.
La empresa tiene una IP publica y las consultas externas caen ahi, ya que se define en el dns de ips, una vez eso tu firewall define si lo deja entrar o no, claramente tiene permitido el acceso al puerto 8019 por http. 
Creo que esta faltando una regla que deje pasar el pedido de ping para el lado interno, ya seria ver la configuracion de tu firewall.
Espero que te sirva y sea eso, sino no se me ocurre otra opcion.

Comment: como podría hacer esto @Jab?, que tipo de regla del firewall debo crear?